# Is there a way to group like strings using TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a log table that contains columns for exception and stack trace data in varchar format.

I would like to query this log table to get counts of similar exceptions.

How would I aggregate similar but not exact matches together?

```
MyApp.MyCustomException: UserId 1 not found
MyApp.MyCustomException: UserId 2 not found
MyApp.MyCustomException: UserId 3 not found
MyApp.MyCustomException: UserId 1 login failed
MyApp.MyCustomException: UserId 2 login failed
MyApp.MyCustomException: UserId 3 login failed
```

The above 6 rows should be counted as

```
"MyApp.MyCustomException: UserId not found" Count:3
"MyApp.MyCustomException: UserId login failed" Count:3
```

The LEFT function would work on the above simple example but not for an exception such as NullReferenceException where the error could happen in several different places in the code.

EDIT: Updated example to more clearly represent the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use `like` with a `case`:

```
select trace, count(*)
from (select l.*,
             (case when trace like 'MyApp.MyCustomException: UserId % not found'
                   then 'MyApp.MyCustomException: UserId not found'
                   when trace like 'MyApp.MyCustomException: UserId % login failed'
                   then 'MyApp.MyCustomException: UserId login failed'
                   else trace
              end) as canonical_tracer
      from log l
     ) l
group by trace;
```

Comment: I could have sworn it wasn't legal to have a wildcard in the middle of a string for a like clause!?

Comment: @user3953989 . . . It is definitely legal.  The wildcards can appear anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using

```
patindex('%pattern%',column)
```

The whole select could be something like

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE patindex('%MyApp.MyCustomException: % not found%',err)>0
```

Make sure not to forget the `%` before and after the end of the pattern. The function will give you the position the pattern was found in a column or `0` if not found.

See here for an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a70e/1

**Edit:**

It can be done with CTE like

```
WITH msgs AS(
 SELECT err,CASE 
   WHEN patindex('%MyApp.MyCustomException: % not found%',err)>0 THEN 1
   WHEN patindex('%Wrong password for %, please try again%',err)>0 THEN 2
   ELSE 0 END msgno FROM tbl )
SELECT msgno, MIN(err) msg1, COUNT(*) cnt FROM msgs GROUP BY msgno
```

see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9565c/2

**2. Edit:**

Or, in a more general way:

```
WITH pats as (SELECT 'UserId' pat -- define various patterns for
    UNION ALL SELECT 'IP'         -- words to be removed after ...  
), pos1 AS (                      -- find position of pattern
 SELECT pat,err msg,patindex('%'+pat+'%',err)+len(pat) p1  FROM tbl,pats 
), pos2 AS (                      -- remove word after pattern
 SELECT LEFT(msg,p1)
   +'<'+pat+'> '
   +SUBSTRING(msg,charindex(' ',SUBSTRING(msg,p1+1,256))+p1,256) msg
 FROM pos1 WHERE p1>len(pat) 
), nonames AS (                  -- find non-specific messages
 SELECT err FROM tbl WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM pos1 WHERE msg=err AND p1>len(pat))
)
SELECT msg, count(*) cnt FROM    -- combine all, group and count
( SELECT msg FROM pos2 UNION ALL SELECT err FROM nonames ) m
GROUP BY msg
```

From all the messages this will remove the first word (=character sequences without blanks) appearing after one of a number of predefined patterns (`pat`). This will make the messages of a certain type look exactly the same so they can be grouped.

You can try it out here (**my final solution**): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2fb9/4

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you provide a working example?

Comment: I didn't know you could use wildcards in the middle of a patindex! Could you also show how to group the counts using this technique?

Comment: For grouping you should somehow could try and "assimilate" the messages by removing the userIds from them. After that they will appear as the "same values". Have not quite worked out how to do it yet ...

Comment: This looks like it will fit the bill! Thanks cars10! I will accept this as the answer once I've had some time to test. I would also like to leave this open for a few hours to see what other possible solutions are available. Thanks again!

Comment: Well, OP already stated: "the only issue is that it will not always be numbers", see above.

Answer (score 0):

This may look quite ugly, but it should be relatively efficient. I use replace to get rid of numbers and extra spaces before grouping. Check it out:

```
WITH yourTable
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        VALUES  ('MyApp.MyCustomException: UserId 1 not found'),
                ('MyApp.MyCustomException: UserId 2 not found'),
                ('MyApp.MyCustomException: UserId 3 not found'),
                ('MyApp.MyCustomException: UserId 1 login failed'),
                ('MyApp.MyCustomException: UserId 2 login failed'),
                ('MyApp.MyCustomException: UserId 3 login failed')
    ) A(col)
)

SELECT  generic_col,
        COUNT(*) AS cnt,
        'Count: ' + CAST(COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR(25)) AS formatted_cnt
FROM yourTable
CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(col,'1',''),'2',''),'3',''),'4',''),'5',''),'6',''),'7',''),'8',''),'9',''),'0',''),'  ',' ')) AS CA(generic_col)
GROUP BY generic_col
```

Comment: The only issue is that it will not always be numbers. In other cases it could be a username, ip address, or other type. This does give me some good ideas however. Thanks!

Comment: This *does* work if userids consist only of the numbers 1 to 10 but in a general case ...?

Comment: Actually it handles the digits individually (except for '10'). That should have probably been just '0' I think. Are you talking about other characters or the range of values from one to ten?

Comment: Nice artwork ... But an ugly solution. *(Note: SQLPolice does **not** downvote)*

Comment: @user3953989 !? Don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: @cars10, shawn is correct. I meant 0 not 10. *See edited answer*

Comment: @user3953989 I actually agree with SQLPolice. It is an ugly solution. Its redemption is that it is relatively efficient.